# Set a height value on an individual CSS Grid row

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a CSS grid layout where I have the top row spanning the entire grid using the `grid-column` property.

Does anyone know how I can set this row to be 100px high and have all the subsequent rows set to a `grid-auto-rows` height of 200px?

I know I can input individual values with `grid-template-rows` for all the specific rows, but there are going to be a lot of divs on the page and don't want to input 100px and then a load of 200px values using this `grid-template-rows` property.

I'm thinking there must be a way to set individual pixel values on certain rows and then have everything else as `grid-auto-rows`?

I can't seem to find how to do this in the docs.

Any help would be awesome!

https://codepen.io/emilychews/pen/dZPJGQ

```css
.gridwrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 2fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 200px;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 200px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

nav {
  background: yellow;
}

.gridwrapper div {
  padding: 1em;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.gridwrapper div:nth-child(odd) {
  background: blue;
}

nav {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
}

/*MAKE DIVS 1FR ON MOBILE*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 736px) {
  .gridwrapper {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="gridwrapper">
  <nav class="grid">1</nav>
  <div class="grid">2</div>
  <div class="grid">3</div>
  <div class="grid">4</div>
  <div class="grid">5</div>
  <div class="grid">6</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> *Does anyone know how I can set this row to be 100px high and have all the subsequent rows set to a `grid-auto-rows` height of 200px?*

Yes. Grid can do this cleanly and easily.

First, you don't need to set a height value on the grid item itself. That overrides one of the great benefits of CSS Grid: the ability to control the dimensions of grid items at the container level.

You know that your grid will always have at least one row: the top row. That's your [**explicit grid**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#explicit-grids).

You don't know how many additional rows there will be. That number is variable and unpredictable. That's your [**implicit grid**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#implicit-grids).

The [**`grid-template-rows`** and **`grid-template-columns`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#track-sizing) properties set track sizes in the explicit grid.

The [**`grid-auto-rows`** and **`grid-auto-columns`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#auto-tracks) properties set track sizes in the implicit grid.

Therefore, this is probably what you're looking for:

```
.gridwrapper{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 100px; /* top row is 100px in height */
    grid-auto-rows: 200px;     /* any new rows created are 200px in height */
}
```

[revised codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rYavyY)

Comment: How can I alter this to also manually set the grid row height of the second row?

Comment: @ZeroDarkThirty:
    `grid-template-rows: 100px 150px; /* top row is 100px in height, 2nd row 150px */
    grid-auto-rows: 200px;     /* any new rows created are 200px in height */`

Answer (score 4):

You can use `grid-template-rows` property.

I guess you are looking for something like this:

https://codepen.io/harora/pen/EbaQxr

Here is a nice reference to the Grid model:
[Grid Model Explained](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

Comment: I never realised you could use grid-auto-rows and grid-template-rows together.  Thanks for this! It was driving me mad.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [**it would be preferable**](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but the "class=grid" used in the HTML does not appear in the CSS.